# Is it affecting performance to await in express.js controllers?

Tags: node.js, express

Saw this example

```
app.get('/users', async function(req, res, next){
  try {
    res.json(await db.getUsers())
  } catch(err) {
    next(err)
  }
})
```

It takes time to query in db, so using await seems make sense.
My question is, will each "get users" request be blocked ? If so the performance will be very bad if running load test.

Can i do this to improve performance ?

```
app.get('/users', function(req, res, next){
  try {
    dbGetUsersCallback(res); // no await here
  } catch(err) {
    next(err)
  }
})

const dbGetUsersCallback = async (res) => {
    const ret = await db.getUsers();
    res.json(res);
}
```

Can this help ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no significant penalty for using await when the operation requires a real async operation like waiting for a database. There is no issue with load.

You need to understand that async/await is equivalent to a promise chain. You are not really "spinning" in a single thread and blocking execution.

async/await is slightly slower than pure callbacks in some cases because of overhead but it is dwarfed by the time needed for the actual database operation, it doesn't matter. Just don't await things that aren't doing any async work and performance will be fine.

Your second version does not work properly if an exception is thrown in the second function. If you call an async function without await it returns a promise, which you are ignoring. If the promise is rejected it will be too late for your exception handler to see it.

Answer (score 1):

It is mostly the same thing, you just moved your main logic into another function.

---

Each `db.getUsers()` will be on standby until they get the actual results from DB, but it will execute very quickly afterwards. Not sure if you can optimise it any further.

---

Also  I think here

```
dbGetUsersCallback(); // no await here
```

you meant:

```
dbGetUsersCallback(res); // no await here
```

Comment: yes i missed "res", will edit the question. For my solution, if i don't call the controller function to be await, i'm hoping the controller won't wait for db query to finish, node/express can move quickly to the next request. Anyway this is my confusing part.

Comment: No, it will serve other requests meanwhile and come back to this one once it actually receives results from the DB.

Comment: check some 'how js event loop works' videos, I had a great one but can't find it anymore unfortunately